# string manipulations

Tags: c#

I have string variable declared globally.I have to append a substring to this string dynamically based on the user input.To do this I use str=str+substring;

In this case the string in str doesn't have meaningful sentence finally ie.,there is no spaces between the words.to make it sense I used the following statement instead,

str=str+" "+substring; or str=str+substring+" ";

here everytime I have to append extra space to the substring before appending this to the main string were additional string processing is required.

Can anybody help on this were i can do this effectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how often you are doing it. If this is intermittent (or in fact pretty-much anything except a tight loop), then forget it; what you have is fine. *Sure* an extra string is generated occasionally (the combined substring/space), but it will be collected at generation 0; very cheap.

If you are doing this *aggressively* (in a loop etc), then use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
// declaration
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
// composition
sb.Append(' ').Append(substring);
...
// obtaining the string
string s = sb.ToString();
```

A final (unrelated) point - re "globally" - if you mean `static`, you might want to synchronize access if you have multiple threads.

Comment: StringBuilder may be overkill if you're only concatenating a few strings on an infrequent basis because of the cost of constructing it. It used to be idiomatic to use string builder to concatenate strings to avoid worst case quadratic complexity due to the string copying that had to be done, but more recent C# compilers have apparently become smart enough to turn chains of string concatenations into String.Concat calls so that the whole operation is done in linear time.

Comment: @Stewart - that has been the case for quite a long time, but only applies to single statements; also, I did already emphasise the two different scenarios here (based on frequency)

Comment: Oh yeah - I didn't read the first sentence properly. Thanks for confirming. I do think that it is worth making the point though. In a lot of places it is still considered a matter of blind faith that one should avoid string concatenation in favour of StringBuilder everywhere, even when StringBuilder is likely to be much more expensive. The quadratic complexity reason is always cited even though it hasn't been true for some time, as you say.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want to achieve exactly?  You could store the words in a list

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
...
words.Add(str);
```

And then delay the string manipulation (i.e. adding the spaces between words) until at the very end.  This way, you're on the fly operation is just an add to a list, and you can do all the complex processing (whatever it may be) at the end.

Comment: (+1)  . In this case we can build the final `string` using aggrigate function like ` String str=words.Aggregate((X1,X2)=>X1+" "+X2);`

Comment: @Pramodh: I guess so, but why would we want to?

Comment: @ Steven Sudit: 'Cause here mrnye adds the strings to a list. So the list will contail `str`, `Substring1` , `substring2` .... But Nanda needs a Single String( As i understood)

Comment: @Pramodh - `string.Join(" ", words)` would be much more efficient; also, I don't think it is *necessarily* as simple as just space-delimiting things *anyway*.

Comment: @Marc Gravell Yeah, it entirely depends if the question states exactly what the person wants to do.  If all you ever want to do is add spaces between words, I would imagine in nearly all scenarios just doing it on the fly like you suggested would work fine.  However the fact Nanda wanted to optimize this piece of would suggest he may be doing something more intense each cycle.  Really need a better description of the problem at hand, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it rarely, you could slightly pretty up the code by doing:

```
str += " " + substring;
```

Otherwise, I'd go with Nanda's solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Nanda: in your case you should use string builder.

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.AppendFormat(" {0}", substring);
```

Comment: If you care about performance you should avoid this. Your code will have to parse the format string at runtime, which has a cost. Jamie and Marc's answers will be quicker than this.