# mysql database selection based on user input in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, app-config

User inputs financial year like 2012-2013, 2013-2014, 2014-2015,.... Based on the financial year input by the user in the text box txtFinYear.text different database should be connected through conn.string. My database names in my MySQL are db_2012_2013, db_2013_2014, db_2014-2015, ....

I am new to C#. At present a single string to connect to a single database defined in app.config file within my c# solution.

Please help

Comment: What have you done so far ? Please post some code and/or a real question.

Comment: Usually you would have several connection strings defined in an app config. There are [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1530361/2589202) that can help you.

Comment: This question is really not related to mysql or databases. It's more about taking text from an input and using it to generate a different string (which just happens to be a connection string). It is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965503/string-manipulations

Comment: Sort of tangential, but if you have a predefined set of dates (2012-2013, 2013-2014, etc) it's significantly easier to provide the users a means to select one, rather than making them input a date into a text box. In terms of your connection conundrum, add the additional connection strings to your app config and implement an `if()` or `switch()`... this should be very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the connection string dynamically, instead of fetching it from app.config as like,

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connStr.Server = "YourServer";
connStr.UserID = "UserId";
connStr.Password = "Pwd";
connStr.Database = txtFinYear.text; //Verify before assigning

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connStr.ToString());
```

Hope this helps...